# Implicit conversions weirdness

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I am trying to understand why exactly an implicit conversion is working in one case, but not in the other. 
Here is an example:

```
   case class Wrapper[T](wrapped: T)
   trait Wrapping { implicit def wrapIt[T](x: Option[T]) = x.map(Wrapper(_))

   class NotWorking extends Wrapping { def foo: Option[Wrapper[String]] = Some("foo") }

   class Working extends Wrapping { 
      def foo: Option[Wrapper[String]] = {
        val why = Some("foo")
        why
      }
    }
```

Basically, I have  an implicit conversion from `Option[T]` to `Option[Wrapper[T]]`, and am trying to define a function, that returns an optional string, that gets implicitly wrapped.

The question is why, when I try to return `Option[String]` directly (`NotWorking` above), I get an error (`found   : String("foo") required: Wrapper[String]`), that goes away if I assign the result to a val before returning it.

What gives?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if this is intended or would be considered a bug, but here is what I think is happening.

In `def foo: Option[Wrapper[String]] = Some("foo")` the compiler will set the expected type of the argument provided to `Some( )` as `Wrapper[String]`. Then it sees that you provided a `String` which it is not what is expected, so it looks for an implicit conversion `String => Wrapper[String]`, can't find one, and fails.

Why does it need that expected type stuff, and doesn't just type `Some("foo")` as `Some[String]` and *afterwards* try to find a conversion?
Because scalac wants to be able to typecheck the following code:

```
case class Invariant[T](t: T)
val a: Invariant[Any] = Invariant("s")
```

In order for this code to work, the compiler can't just type `Invariant("s")` as `Invariant[String]` because then compilation will fail as `Invariant[String]` is not a subtype of `Invariant[Any]`. The compiler needs to set the expected type of `"s"` to `Any` so that it can see that `"s"` is an instance of `Any` before it's too late.

In order for both this code and your code to work out correctly, I think the compiler would need some kind of backtracking logic which it doesn't seem to have, perhaps for good reasons.

The reason that your `Working` code does work, is that this kind of type inference does not span multiple lines. Analogously `val a: Invariant[Any] = {val why = Invariant("s"); why}` does *not* compile.